# C++ char class findCharIndex

Tags: c++, class, character, c-strings

```
int String::findCharIndex(const char &c) const
{
    for (int i =0; i < this->getLength();i++)
    {   
    if ( this->operator[](i) == c)
    {
        return i;
        break;
    }
    else
        return -1;
 }
```

I have been working with this function that returns the Index of the character c in a c-string. The function works fine with character, but if c is a number, it still result -1.

Example:

The first index of '2' in "I have 2 dogs" is -1.

Please tell me why because it suppose to be 7?

Comment: When you say "The first index of '2'", do you mean the first index of `'2'` or of `2`? A [mre] would leave this unambiguous.

Comment: @chris I mean the position of '2' in the string "I have 2 dogs". So the result should be 7, not -1.

Comment: The code shown will not compile, as it is missing a `}` to close the `for` loop

Answer (score 4):

### Your `return -1;` statement is in the wrong place.

It is attached to the `else` of the `if` inside the loop, and thus it will be reached when `this->operator[](i) == c` evaluates as false.  Effectively, if the 1st  `char` is a match, you call `return i;`, otherwise you call `return -1;`. You are ignoring the 2nd and subsequent `char`s completely.

The `return -1;` statement needs to be moved below the loop, so that it is reached only if the entire string is scanned without finding any matches, eg

```
int String::findCharIndex(const char &c) const {
    for (int i = 0; i < this->getLength(); ++i) {
        if (this->operator[](i) == c) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; // <-- moved here
}
```

Comment: @HoangMy no, because 1) the `break` is never reached because of the `return i;` right above it, and 2) when `this->operator[](i) == c` evaluates as false then the `else` is entered, not the `if` and your `else` calls `return -1`. Be mindful of how you use `{}` braces!